# Is $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ dense in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ in the sup-norm?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

The question is simply, if $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ dense in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ in the sup-norm, that is the norm in $L^\infty (\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you have a sequence in $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ that converges uniformly to the constant function $1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: You're right. I mixed the uniform convergence with weak operator convergence.

Comment: to the constant function 1 yes, but is there a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 0} \subset C_0^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. with $f$ bounded measurable? I always was convinced that $C_0^\infty$ was dense in $L^\infty$ :P

Comment: How would you approximate $1$? For each $f \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ you have $\lim\limits_{\lvert x\rvert \to\infty} f(x) = 0$, hence $\lVert f - 1\rVert_\infty \geqslant 1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** the uniform limit of $C_0$ functions has to go to $0$ at infinity

Comment: Here, $C_0$ means compactly supported, but ok I agree, the uniform limit should be $C_0^\infty$ right? So the answer is no. But, can we approximate functions in $L^\infty$ a.e. by functions in $C_0^\infty$?